# magento modern - display of attributes in TAB

Tags: magento

If you go here:

```
http://pro-tools-training.com/new-magento/index.php/video-1/youtube.html
```

and click "**BUZZ/INFO**" tab, you see the following text:

```
BUZZ
```

---

Why does the attribute name appear and why does it bump my text to the center????

How to fix?? I just want to show whatever I place in the attribute text box, not the name and not center justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the page minutely using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), you will find that in one of the "`TABLE`" HTML tag (whose "`id`" value is "**product-attribute-specs-table**"), the first row contains a column which is given below:-

```
<th class="label">BUZZ</th>
```

Now the second column is your text, so it seems that the first column is either coming somewhere from Magento by default, or has been inserted in the "`PHTML`" template page unknowingly. So what you need to do is to remove the above-mentioned column from that proper template page (if you are able to find that one), or you will need to work on some CSS.

If you need to do some CSS work, then the code will be somewhat like below:-

```
div#product_tabs_additional_contents table#product-attribute-specs-table th.label {display: none;}
div#product_tabs_additional_contents table#product-attribute-specs-table td {padding-left:8px;}
```

The above will work for you, but you need to put this CSS in a CSS file in the proper theme interface/name folder, which you are using.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it is coming from magento by default but I will try the CSS...many thanks